# Caculated time One Point Multiplication with double and method

Tags: elliptic-curves, performance

I am using double and add method for point multiplication in affine coordinates. How we compute 1PM in double and method?

Di Wang said one point multiplication consists of repeated addition and doubling operations, so the calculated time of point multiplication

```
#ADD*1ADD + #DBL*1DBL
```

more less equals 1PM. But when I calculate with the formula show different result:

```
#ADD*1ADD + #DBL*1DBL = 127#ADD*2ms + 256#DBL*3ms = 766ms
```

Actual 1PM = 421ms.

This is a huge difference. Can anyone explain this difference?

Double and add algorithm requires log2(n) iterations of point doubling and addition to compute the full-point multiplication.

So I think that: $2^y = n$ where $y$ is number point addition or doubling

Edited:

Double and Add Method d=11=(1011)
Example : 11P= 2.((2.(2P))+P) + P, it consist of 3DBL + 2ADD. So 1PM less equal to #ADD*1ADD + #DBL*1DBL = 2ADD*timeof1ADD + 3DBL*timeof1ADD = time of 1PM.

If i have d lenghth = 256 bit, and i use Double-and-Method, How many #ADD and #DOUBLE iterations in there? DiWang said 127#ADD and 256#DOUBLE, can somebody explain how get this number?

Comment: I've formatted your question. Please do not use '#' for formulas but use Latex (or ask for help). I'm not sure about your equations to I've turned them into code fragments. Please edit your question again to clear things up. What do you mean with `ADD*ADD`? Please reread your question before hitting the post button.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes `#ADD` is supposed to be the number of additions.

Comment: @CodesInChaos ok, the original showed it as caption instead. Glad I at least edited that out. We can leave it as preformatted code then I suppose, unless somebody knows the correct Latex tags for this...

Comment: Alfred, if you post a time in ms then I suppose that is for a specific runtime. Could you post that runtime configuration ? Chances are that somebody here knows about the implementation specifics.

Comment: How certain are you on the timings of the double and add routines?  If they are moderately faster than you think, that'd explain the performance difference.

Comment: If addition, there are more efficient algorithms to compute point multiplication than double-and-add; if you're timing some software to obtain 421msec, perhaps that code is using one of the more efficient algorithms